# How to use the call back from the android OS whenever any changes occur in of battery percentage, time, calendar, location, who is calling etc

Tags: android, callback, mobile-application, android-os-handler

I was trying to do an app and I got stuck in retrieving the status of battery percentage, time, calendar, location, who is calling etc., and since indeed to continuously track the status of such things the polling logic is not a good idea. So, I was thinking to use the call back from the android OS whenever any changes occur in those conditions to my app, but I cannot find any relevant library file or API, neither a source to learn that.

I have gone through few android API classes.Even though these classes satisfy my needs, the application of these as far as I found are with polling approach which may drain the battery continuously. So I would like to use the call back approach. the api-classes I checked out are :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511455/Android-Phone-Status-Sample.html

Comment: can u show ur effort

Comment: I have gone through few android API classes.Even though these classes satisfy my  needs, the application of these as far as we found are with polling approach may drain the battery continuously. So I would like to use the call back approach. the apis we checked out are :

Comment: These are links for android classes :                                                          http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.html                                                                                  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellLocation.html                                                                                                         http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511455/Android-Phone-Status-Sample

Comment: pls put this information into the question